# Google API : Google Chart Gauge Animation not working with Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts, google-visualization

```
setInterval(function () {
    drawGuage();
}, 5000);

   var chart1 = null;
  function drawGuage() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetGuageData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data;

                var options = {
                            title: 'Run-rate',
                            width: 500, height: 500,
                            min: 0, max: 120,
                            redFrom: 0, redTo: 80,
                            yellowFrom: 101, yellowTo: 120,
                            greenFrom: 81, greenTo: 100,
                            minorTicks: 5,
                            majorTicks: ['0', '30', '60', '90', '120'],
                            animation: {
                                duration: 1000,
                                easing: 'inAndOut'
                            },
                        };
                if (chart1 === null) {
                    chart1 = new google.visualization.Gauge($("#guageChart")[0]);
                     data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['Label', 'Value'],
                        ['Production', 0]
                    ]);
                    chart1.draw(data, options);
                    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart1, 'ready', function () {
                              data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                              chart1.draw(data, options);
                            });
                }
                else {
                    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d); 
                }
                chart1.draw(data, options);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
        });
}
```

Above is my code for Google Gauge chart. Animation is not working. Its just fixed to one value always. Guage needle is not moving on interval set.
when the data is refreshed, the Gauge lines are not animated, but instead they are redrawn from new. I would like to see the cool animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you're drawing the chart with the data,
before the `'ready'` event has time to react.

move the last `draw` statement, inside the `if` statement, see comments below...

```
            if (chart1 === null) {
                chart1 = new google.visualization.Gauge($("#guageChart")[0]);
                 data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Label', 'Value'],
                    ['Production', 0]
                ]);
                chart1.draw(data, options);
                google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart1, 'ready', function () {
                          data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                          chart1.draw(data, options);
                        });
            }
            else {
                data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d); 
            }
            chart1.draw(data, options);  // <-- move this up one line
```

---

```
            if (chart1 === null) {
                chart1 = new google.visualization.Gauge($("#guageChart")[0]);
                 data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Label', 'Value'],
                    ['Production', 0]
                ]);
                chart1.draw(data, options);
                google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart1, 'ready', function () {
                          data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                          chart1.draw(data, options);
                        });
            }
            else {
                data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d); 
                chart1.draw(data, options);  // <-- to here
            }
```

Comment: I have another question is it possible in Google table chart to put a flash light color for a column cell based on value of that column cell like we have color formatter.